# JavaScript variables concatenated (Khan Academy)

Tags: javascript, variables, khan-academy

I'm a high school student and I'm working on learning JavaScript with Khan Academy, and I came across a problem I don't know the answer to. Here's my script:

```
var name = function() {
    var yourName = "Jack";
    var xP = random(0, 300);
    var yP = random(0, 300);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textSize(30);
    text("Hiiii, " + yourName, xP, yP);    
};
name();
```

It says "Now that you've defined the yourName variable as your name, pass that variable into the text() command, concatenated with the greeting. "

I can't see where I'm making my error. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Hey can you share the link where you are putting in this code so that we can better help you.

Comment: Is your code inside a closure, or in global scope? What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "name" is a reserved word. Use an other variable name, and you should be good to go.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: `name` is not a reserved keyword. The problem is that the property `"name"` of `window` has a getter and setter, which stores the stringified value of the function instead of the function itself.

Comment: Check the link though. It's not a keyword, but there is a built-in object or function called "name", and it says that you should avoid using it. Your code works for me when I change the variable name.

Comment: Can't help you with that, I'm afraid. The only problem in the presented code is the variable name "name". Check your other functions that you use for errors.

Comment: Looks like it was really me. I had the variable outside the function. Thanks for the help!